# How to use pandas to import and reformat multiple excels?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I tried combining multiple excel (around 30 different ones) into one single excel using python. Most of the excels looks something like this:

```
title1 title2 title3  title4
name   price  gender  true or false
name   price  gender  true or false
... and so on
```

Here is the code I use to combine the excel and make it into one data frame:

```
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
    files = os.listdir(cwd)  
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.XLSX'):
            df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
```

However, some of the excels are out of order like so (some of them have other format, the below one is just an example):

```
title3 title2 title1  title4
gender price  name    true or false
gender price  name    true or false
... and so on
```

So when combining using the code above, the result data frame will be messed up.

I wish the result to look like this despite the different excel formatting:

```
title1 title2 title3  title4
name   price  gender  true or false
name   price  gender  true or false
... and so on
```

Can someone help me fix the code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.concat` to merge all your data (and `pathlib` to get file names):

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

cwd = pathlib.Path.cwd()
files = cwd.glob('*.XLSX')

# desktop_dir = pathlib.Path(r'C:/users/xxx/Desktop')
# files = desktop_dir.glob('*.XLSX')

data = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    data.append(df)

df = pd.concat(data)
```

```
>>> df
   title3 title2 title1  title4
0  gender  price   name   False
1  gender  price   name   False
0  gender  price   name    True
1  gender  price   name    True
```

Comment: hi, what if I only want to search file on the desktop, is there like a path code for glob?

Comment: replace `cwd = ...` by `desktop_dir = pathlib.Path(r'C:/users/xxx/Desktop')`. I updated my answer, look at the commented code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `df.append` try using `df = pd.concat(df, pd.read_excel(file))`

This will append the two dataframes one after the other taking columns into account

Comment: Use `concat` instead of `df.append` is a  good idea however create a new dataframe at each iteration is not a good idea. Prefer append to a list (or a dict) and `concat` at once.